# insert data in dynamic table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i am usginf this but getting error can u provide a solution.

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(500);
SET @TableName = N'CREATE TABLE businessmaster_'+
                 CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GetDate()-1,112)+
                 N' ( contentid int,Businessname varchar(50) )';
print @TableName



  declare  @sql varchar(100)    

  SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO'+ @TableName+' (contentid,Businessname) SELECT top 10 contentid,Businessname FROM businessmaster';
EXEC (@sql);
```

Comment: First there is size limit issue `@TableName`, `@sql`

Comment: Also it seems that a space is missing after `INTO` .

Comment: This is so not the way to work with tables in a SQL database.  Don't split the data into separate tables by date.

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: You don't even create the table, how you can insert on it?

Comment: getting that one-

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TABLE'.

Comment: `print @sql` - you're gonna be surprised.

Answer (score 1):

You did not create the table, it should look like this

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(500);

SET @TableName = N'businessmaster_'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GetDate()-1,112);

EXEC (N'CREATE TABLE '+@TableName +' ( contentid int,Businessname varchar(50) )')

print @TableName
declare  @sql varchar(100)    

SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO '+ @TableName+' (contentid,Businessname) SELECT top 10 contentid,Businessname FROM businessmaster';
EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: I was just writing an answer but I think it was going to be (roughly) the same as this.

Comment: This query make sure that the table is created. What's kind of error you are getting? I believed that it comes from your select query. You can change your query like this, SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO '+ @TableName+' (contentid,Businessname) SELECT 1,''aa'''; It's works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You did not create your table, how can you insert data to table not exist:

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @TableName = N'businessmaster_'+
                 CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GetDate()-1,112);

SET @SQL = N' CREATE TABLE '+@TableName + N' ( contentid int,Businessname varchar(50) )';

EXECUTE (@SQL);

SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO '+ @TableName+' (contentid,Businessname) SELECT top 10 contentid,Businessname FROM businessmaster';

EXECUTE (@SQL);
```

**[Demo](http://rextester.com/SHLBMN43024)**.

Comment: @user8932855 it's more or less the same as me. Why did you get errors in my query @@

Comment: when i run ur query getting that one.
businessmaster_20171114
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'contentid'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'Businessname'.